# How to share images between subdomains?

Tags: php, css, subdomain

I have a domain, lets call it 'oficial' and a subdomain.

This subdomain is a copy from oficial in design terms speaking (CSS, images, etc)

My problem is how to use all the images and styles from oficial domain ?

I tried to include CSS files into subdomain like this `include(/var/www/oficial/styles/style.css);`
It worked but all the classes with `background-image` property didn't work because they are declared like this:

```
background:url(../images/image.jpg);
```

so, it is trying to reach images folder into the subdomain directory, and there is the real problem.

I thought to put full URL instead, but I would have to modify all CSS files with background-image property

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you `including` your stylesheets? Just load them through the original link?

Comment: You are confusing directory layout and URL layout: the web browser reading your CSS file knows nothing about how files are stored on your server, only the URLs it is going to request. You can configure your server to respond to those requests however you want, e.g. using Apache's mod_rewrite or mod_alias functions, or whatever equivalents IIS / nginx / etc provide.

Comment: @PeeHaa well, it was just an idea that I tried.
IMSoP Thanks for your help, I'll give it a shot

Comment: Why not just use absolute URLs on the images and they can all be served from one domain and you don't even need copies of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load the stylesheet inline.

You can link to style sheets externally like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mystyle.css">
```

That way, the background images will be relative to where the stylesheet is hosted and not the page where it is embedded.

Comment: Yeah, is a good idea.
I was thinking on a harder solution but it was pretty easy.